# Phoenix additional layout variables like @inner

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am looking to add additional **layout** parameters like the `@inner` for the layout. For example `@title` for the `<title>@title</title>` and an area for onload javascript for individual pages.

```
window.onload = function () {
   @onload_js
}
```

These are set in the layout, so I am not sure the best way to handle these in Phoenix. Thanks :D.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For the page title, you can simply pass a value through from your controller:

```
def edit(conn, params) do
  render(conn, "edit.html", page_title: "Edit The Thing")
end

<head>
  <title><%= assigns[:page_title] || "Default Title" %></title>
</head>
```

Note that this uses `assigns[:page_title]` instead of `@page_title` or `assigns.page_title` as they will error if the `:page_title` key is not present in assigns.

---

For including templates (your script example) there is [render_existing/3](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/1.0.0/Phoenix.View.html#render_existing/3) (and [the docs for the same function in the latest version of Phoenix](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render_existing/3)).

The documentation gives a similar example to what you requested so I have copied it here for convenience:

> Consider the case where the application layout allows views to dynamically render a section of script tags in the head of the document. Some views may wish to inject certain scripts, while others will not.

```
<head>
  <%= render_existing view_module(@conn), "scripts.html", assigns %>
</head>
```

> Then the module for the @inner view can decide to provide scripts with either a precompiled template, or by implementing the function directly, ie:

```
def render("scripts.html", _assigns) do
  "<script src="...">"
end
```

> To use a precompiled template, create a scripts.html.eex file in the templates directory for the corresponding view you want it to render for. For example, for the UserView, create the scripts.html.eex file at web/templates/user/.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for the explanation. Helped out immensely at figuring it out.

Comment: That works but what if you want to add a lot of page specific meta data. Your controller methods would becomes a mess quickly! Plus controllers should be for business logic anyway. I recommend using **render_existing/2** function as described   [here](http://blog.danielberkompas.com/2016/01/28/seo-tags-in-phoenix.html)