# Include Javascript on Certain Pages in Phoenix Framework Application

Tags: javascript, elixir, phoenix-framework

I've got a bit of Javascript that I only want to include on certain pages in my Phoenix application.

Right now I've got the Javascript inside a script tag in `myapp/web/templates/post/form.html.eex`.

I understand that I can move the JavaScript to `web/static/js/app.js` ...but I don't want to include the Javascript on every page (it's only required on 2 specific pages).

What's the best way to load this section of Javascript on certain pages in my application without duplication the code and violating the DRY principle?

Comment: Take a look at this answer (the `render_existing` section) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356096/phoenix-additional-layout-variables-like-inner/32356624#32356624

Comment: Thanks Gazler - not sure exactly how to apply that answer to my situation though. Could you write an answer here for me?

Comment: Also think about the concept of _running_ the JS on specific pages, vs _loading_ the JS conditionally. You may not need to care about if/when/where it _loads_, only when it _runs_. This can be accomplished by wrapping the `Object.do_things()` call in a condition checking for presence of a certain selector (like your form).

Comment: @Todd That's a good point but, all else being equal (which it often *isn't*), it's better not to load code that won't be run.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### 1.

Put all that javascript from **form.html.eex** into its own file (maybe something like **js/posts.js**).

Add this at the bottom:

```
export var Post = { run: function() {
  // put initializer stuff here
  // for example:
  // $(document).on('click', '.remove-post', my_remove_post_function)
}}
```

#### 2.

In your **app.html**, under `<script src="#{static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js")}"></script>` add this:

```
<%= render_existing @view_module, "scripts.html", assigns %>
```

#### 3.

Then, in your view (probably **views/post_view.ex**), add a method like this:

```
def render("scripts.html", _assigns) do
  ~s{<script>require("web/static/js/posts").Post.run()</script>}
  |> raw
end
```

#### Conclusion

Now the javascript file **post.js** will only be loaded when the post view is being used.

Answer (score 7):

Here is one way to achieve this.

The JavaScript you have in the script tag, you move that into a separate file.

You divide your "regular" javascript (to be included in every page) and this custom javascript (to be included in some specific pages) into separate directories. e.g. app/common/standard.js and app/custom/unique.js

You modify your brunch-config.js to as follows:

```
module.exports = {
 files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: {
        'custom.js': /^app[\\\/]common[\\\/][\S*?]\.js/,
        'app.js': /^app[\\\/]common[\\\/][\S*?]\.js/
        }
    }
}
```

Then you include app.js in all pages,

```
<script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>
```

but custom.js only in page (or layout) templates that need it.

```
<script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/custom.js") %>"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to make use of page-specific classes/elements. For example, the following code in `app.js` will ensure that the code only gets executed on the `lesson/show` page, since only that page has an element with the id `#lesson-container`:

```
import { startLesson } from './lesson/show.ts';

if (document.querySelector('#lesson-container')) {
  startLesson();
}
```

Comment: Note that this approach is about controlling when JS will _run_, as opposed to controlling if it _loads_ or not.

Answer (score 3):

This is based on [Gazler's comment on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629942/include-javascript-on-certain-pages-in-phoenix-framework-application#comment60876534_36629942) and is a *slightly* more general answer than [the one submitted by cmititiuc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40203763/173497). You don't strictly need to wrap your page-specific JavaScript code like in that answer, nor do anything beyond import your page-specific file in the page-specific `script` element.

### Layout templates

Use [`Phoenix.View.render_existing/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render_existing/3) in your layouts like this:

```
<head>
  <%= render_existing @view_module, "scripts.html", assigns %>
</head>
```

... or this:

```
<head>
  <%= render_existing @view_module, "scripts." <> @view_template, assigns %>
</head>
```

For the first example, this will render a `"scripts.html"` template if one exists for the relevant view module.

For the second example, a `"scripts." <> @view_template` template, e.g. *scripts.form.html*, will be rendered if it exists.

If the 'scripts' template does NOT exist for a view module, nothing will be output in the page HTML.

### View modules

For the first example using `render_existing/3` in the layout template, you'd add code like this to the post view module:

```
def render("scripts.html", _assigns) do
  ~E(<script src="file.js"></script>)
end
```

... and for the second you'd add code like this:

```
def render("scripts.show.html", _assigns) do
  ~E(<script src="show-file.js"></script>)
end

def render("scripts.index.html", _assigns) do
  ~E(<script src="index-file.js"></script>)
end
```

### Details

The difference between `render_existing` and `render` is that the former won't raise an error if the referenced template does NOT exist (and nothing will be output in the page HTML in that case either).

[The `~E` sigil](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.html#sigil_E/2) provides "HTML safe EEx syntax inside source files" and is similar to (in most cases, or maybe even always) the corresponding code from [cmititiuc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40203763/173497):

```
~s{<script>require("web/static/js/posts").Post.run()</script>}
|> raw
```

### Conclusion

In general then, for any page for which you want to import specific JavaScript files via `script` elements in the page `head` (or at the end of the `body`), or link CSS files, or do anything to the page output in a portion thereof otherwise handled by the layout, you'd use `render_existing` in the layout template as above and then implement appropriate `render` clauses in the view modules for those pages.

And further, there's no reason why you couldn't use something like *both* of the two examples above so that, for any view module and its templates, you could both:

- Include some script(s) (or CSS files or otherwise manipulate the HTML output of in a layout template) for *all* the view module templates (but not all templates for the entire app)
- Include some script(s) (or ...) for only *a single* template

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

Put your code in a new .js file.  Include the script tag with a source to the file path in the relevant html files.

Comment: What is the file path for the js file when it's in `myapp/web/static/js/myscripts.js`? It's like this now and the Javascript is not being loaded.

Comment: You can get the path with `<script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/myscript.js") %>"></script>`

Comment: This errors out to: `assign @conn not available in eex template.`