# JS and CSS file for each view Phoenix Elixir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am finding few ways to get my work routine good with Phoenix as I have with rails, There are some perspectives which I am looking in Phoenix are.

1: In rails, I have my controller and my view, also the CSS and JS files alongside, When I want to include CSS files only in one relevant view, I only do as

```
<%= yield :head %>
```

and In my View file, I only do

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "views/index/landing.css" %>
<% end %>
```

That's it. My CSS file is only loading for my relevant view.

2: For JS, I have application.js file in which I included my other libs and in the end, I have admin.js in which I have included my every other file as

```
//= require jquery
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require admin/admin.js
```

admin.js.coffee file

```
#= require admin/sign_up.js.coffee
#= require admin/company.js.coffee
#= require admin/user.js.coffee
```

3: For every JS file What I am doing is, e.g for Signup view's JS file I have done as under, in the very end of the file,

```
window.initializeSignUp = ->
  onSignUp()
```

after this What I only need in my sign up view is

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    window.initializeSignUp();
  });
</script>
```

Now it's only calling that method of Signup and everything is working fine.
On the other hand, I love Elixir it's a very good and lovable language to work in, BUT whenever I start project in it, I already got afraid of Brunch and how Assets are going to be handled.

**for those who will read the question and will just downvote without even understanding the main issue here**: Am a newbie to Phoenix for creating an APP with views and assets, etc.

I just need a clear and correct answer to work with Phoenix without using brunch or any web-pack solution, But a normal way, Is that possible in possible?

Comment: What Rails does for (2) is not "normal". Rails has its own brunch/webpack-like thing which does this concatenation. Phoenix does not include any such functionality.

Comment: I am only finding a reliable way to solve the problem for a person who don't know Brunch or web pack.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question has been [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629942/include-javascript-on-certain-pages-in-phoenix-framework-application). The answer shows how to add page specific javascript but the same technique can be done for your css styles.

Here's a [good explanation](http://www.jeramysingleton.com/phoenix-templates-are-just-functions/) of how templates/views work in Phoenix.